# DB2: Trigger does not work on inserted row

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

I have an app that writes user-specific data to a db2 table and I need to anonymize some of them without having access to the app code.
So I created a trigger that should replace the newly created cell values on INSERT:

```
db2 create trigger anonymizer
  after insert on my.users for each statement mode db2sql
  update my.users set DISPLAY_NAME='Anonymous'
```

The trigger works and does the anonymization properly for all rows EXCEPT the newly created one.
How can I make the trigger change ALL rows?

Comment: What's your Db2 platform and version? Your statement is not correct for Db2 for LUW at least. Check the [dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=8000ac3c9896d9ed7c75f4147991ce88). `BEFORE INSERT` trigger is more suitable for the case, when you have to anonymize inserted row(s) only.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, my DB2 11.1.4 runs on Windows.
Ok, I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223400/before-insert-trigger-with-stored-procedure-call-db2-luw-9-5

Modified the statement as follows:
"db2 create trigger anonymizer no cascade before insert on my.users referencing new as r for each row mode db2sql set r.DISPLAY_NAME='Anonymous'"

But, INSERT is still executed with the real name, the trigger does not touch it...

Comment: Check the [dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=7ef1c10ca9aee4b7581e0648842cbd9b). The trigger works as expected. Edit your question with complete example reproducing some non-expected behavior.

Comment: Ok, dbfiddle brought me to the solution. A manual INSERT from command line was triggered and changed properly while creation of entries from the application did not run the trigger. By some reason, it works now with a "BEFORE UPDATE' (db2 create trigger anonymizer2 no cascade before update on my.users referencing new as r for each row mode db2sql set r.DISPLAY_NAME='Anonymous'). No idea why, because, I see newly created rows after each click from the application and assumed that only an INSERT could do that. But anyway, it works now - thank you so much for guiding me into the right direction!!

Comment: You may want to have a look at: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=security-row-column-access-control-rcac